# Microsoft Print to PDF to stream instead of file

Tags: delphi

We use the `Microsoft Print to PDF` to print PDF files.

This is the "magic" we use:

```
procedure TMSPDFPrinter.BeginDoc;
var
  DeviceMode: THandle;
  Device, Driver, Port: array[0..80] of Char;
  filename: WideString;
begin
  if not DirectoryExists(ExtractFilePath(_Filename)) then
    raise Exception.Create(Format('Directory %s not exists! Cannot create PDF file.', [ExtractFilePath(_Filename)]));
  filename := _Filename;
  Printer.PrinterIndex := Printer.Printers.IndexOf('Microsoft Print to PDF');
  Printer.GetPrinter(Device, Driver, Port, DeviceMode);
  Printer.SetPrinter(Device, Driver, @filename[1], 0);
  inherited;
end;
```

Everything works perfectly fine. But is there any way I can change it to print to a stream instead of a file? I am kind of out of ideas.

Comment: Off-topic hint: Write `raise Exception.CreateFmt('Directory "%s" does not exist. Cannot create PDF file.', [ExtractFilePath(_Filename)])` instead.

Comment: Also, use `PChar(FileName)` instead of `@filename[1]`. The latter may give you a range check error if the string is empty. You very much don't want that.

Comment: If you can't find a direct solution consider using WebView4Delphi. You can open the file in the browser and call TWVBrowser.PrintToPdfStream. Then use the TWVBrowser.OnPrintToPdfStreamCompleted event to copy the stream.

Comment: @SalvadorDíazFau there shouldn't be a file in the first place

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - why do you want a _stream_ to begin with? Please edit your Q instead of wasting comments.